Diagonalizing each block of block diagonalized matrix
We have a $n\times n$ matrix $A$ , which is also block diagonalized into
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}
A_1 & & &\\
    & A_2 & &\\
& & \ddots & \\
 & & & A_s
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
And we also know that A can be diagonalized, how to prove that each block $A_i$ can be diagonalized?
I've already known that this can be proved using Jordan canonical form, but I wonder if there is another way to prove this using more fundamental knowledge (Suppose I've leant no more than the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of matrices)
Below are my progress:
Suppose A has distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_s$, then we have
$
A(\vec{\beta_1^{(1)}},\cdots,\vec{\beta_{a_1}^{(1)}},\cdots,\vec{\beta_1^{(s)}},\cdots,\vec{\beta_{a_s}^{(s)}})=$
$$(\vec{\beta_1^{(1)}},\cdots,\vec{\beta_{a_1}^{(1)}},\cdots,\vec{\beta_1^{(s)}},\cdots,\vec{\beta_{a_s}^{(s)}})
\left(\begin{matrix}
\lambda_1 & & & & & & \\
&\ddots &  & & & &\\
& & \lambda_1 & & & &\\
& & & \ddots & & & \\
& & & & \lambda_s & &\\
& & & & & \ddots & \\
&&&&&&\lambda_s
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
if I could prove that each block $A_i$'s size is also $a_i\times a_i$ (don't use Jordan canonical form!), then my problem can be easily solved. However, this is where I'm stuck. Any help is appreciated!

Have you learned about minimal polynomials, invariant (or stable) subspaces, and the theorem that a linear operator (corresponds to a square matrix) is diagonalizable if and only if its minimal operator is the product of distinct linear factors? These would give a simple proof to the result.

@Duong Ngo  Well, what I want is to use the basic knowledge to solve this... Your answer is a good way to comprehend this question, but I need a more rigorous proof

@Rodri Answers here would help.

Please do not answer in the comments, @ToniMhax.

(This is a deleted comment i wrote). The block diagonalized form of $A$ call it $B$ is diagonalizable since $A$ is diagonalizable. Suppose one $A_i$ is not diagonalizable, this means that one eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ of $A_i$ which is also of $B$ has a geometric multiplicity less than its algebraic multiplicity. But this is a contradiction since the eigenvectors of $\lambda_i$ as an eigenvalue for $B$ are the eigenvectors of $A_i$ (for $\lambda_i$) completed by zero entries.
